# Simultaneously move wpf and c++ windows

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi

I have a main form which is developed in wpf. We have used DragMove to move the window when user clicks on some areas in the window.

We also have another window which is developed in c++ and is designed like an add-on sidebar and is a separate process.

I want that the c++ window should also move when I am moving the main form.
I have the handle of both the windows and can pass win32 messages.

Can someone tell how I can intercept the move commands in main form and also pass them to the extra window.

Comment: Completely unclear, what you are looking for. Sounds like [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681.aspx) is, what you are looking for. But it would totally help, if you abstracted the problem, without intermixing your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

To intercept the movement of your WPF application you can listen for the event named [Window.LocationChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.locationchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using the [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function you can manipulate a window handle. You will have to find this handling by using [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) based on the process id of the C++ application.